# How to set Light Theme to .NET MAUI Application on IOS for Status Bar Text Color to be white

Tags: .net, themes, statusbar, .net-maui

I am trying to set the Status Bar color on IOS to white when I want to change the background of the status bar. How would I do this?

Comment: This has been done in a PR, you can check [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/998) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code to change the Status Bar Color and the style.

```
<ContentPage 
...  
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit" ...>
        
        <ContentPage.Behaviors>
             <toolkit:StatusBarBehavior StatusBarColor="Yellow" StatusBarStyle="DarkContent" />
     </ContentPage.Behaviors>
...
</ContentPage>
```